# Need Help Understanding Unreferenced Object

Tags: java, object

I was learning about objects on the Java Oracle tutorials and I learned how to reference an objects fields. They gave me two ways to do it, and the the first method I understood. However, the second method of doing it confused me. This is the code:

```
int height = new Rectangle().height;
```

I understand the statement itself, but it is what the tutorial says that confused me. The tutorial said "This statement creates a new Rectangle object and immediately gets its height. In essence, the statement calculates the default height of a Rectangle. **Note that after this statement has been executed, the program no longer has a reference to the created Rectangle, because the program never stored the reference anywhere. The object is unreferenced, and its resources are free to be recycled by the Java Virtual Machine.** But wait wasn't it referenced with the variable name "height"? So how is it unreferenced? I understand this:

```
Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(1,2,3);// random arguements don't mind them
```

So what makes this line of code referenced but the other unreferenced?

Comment: First scenario - objects got created on the fly, accessed its variable and then object life is finished thus unreferenced. Second scenario - Actually you are creating an object and assigning it meaning memory allocation happened and object is still alive which can referenced in the scope where it has been created thus it is called still referenced.

Comment: @IndraUprade But didn't I also do that in the first scenario? I created an object reference named "height" and allocated memory using the "new" operator. Isn't the rect1 that same as height? Or is the reason the first scenario is not referenced because I simply called the height field only?

Comment: Yes the object created in first scenario is not referenced, you are only using its property and in second scenario actually you are using object reference as rect1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to read it too literally.

> But wait wasn't it referenced with the variable name "height"? So how is it unreferenced?

You could say that an *anonymous* reference was created and well... referenced once to get the height.

> Note that after this statement has been executed, the program no longer has a reference to the created Rectangle, because the program never stored the reference anywhere. The object is unreferenced, and its resources are free to be recycled by the Java Virtual Machine.

Since the reference is anonymous it cannot be used anywhere else. Hence **after that statement** there is no way to reference the object. If so then why keep it in memory - it may as well be garbage collected.